# Запуск файла из dbgrid delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe, dbgrid, delphi-xe7

Есть связка БД mysql + dbgrid, dbgrid отображает данные (имя, размер, путь и т.д.)
Есть 2 моих редактора (я учусь), через которые нужно открыть jpg или txt, а все остальное это уже диалоговое окно открыть "с помощью". Никак не получается реализовать, редакторы jpg, txt открываются сами, но не открывает сами файлы через эти редакторы, отдельно запускаю диалоговое окно открыть "с помощью", говорит что не удается найти...в 1й раз в жизни пишу вопрос на форуме...(вообще), не судите строго. Вот 2 куска кода, что наскреб:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
var[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
  MyFile: String;
begin
  MyFile := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('filename').AsString;
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar('PhotoEitor.exe'),
  pchar(MyFile), nil, SW_RESTORE);
  //ИЛИ
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar('rundll32.exe'),
  PChar('shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL ' + MyFile), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Comment: PhotoEitor.exe - в имено нет опечатки случайно?

Comment: Что записано в MyFile?

Comment: PhotoEditor.exe сидит в корневой папке проекта, обычный редактор типа paint

Comment: В MyFile записано имя первого столбца, такое же имя в мускуле бд

Comment: @Асхаттт - переведите :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом вызове `MyFile` должен включать полный путь к файлу, который Вы хотите открыть для редактирования, а не только имя файла:

```
var
  filePath, fileName, fullName: String;
begin
  filePath := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('filepath').AsString;
  fileName := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('filename').AsString;
  fullName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(filePath) + fileName;
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar('PhotoEditor.exe'),
    PChar(fullName), nil, SW_RESTORE);
```

Comment: Вот тут и трабла, по щелчку на любую строку через shellexec открыть любой файл если предусмотрен моими редакторами в данном случае PhotoEditor.exe или диалог окно открыть с помощью и там уже выбирам mp3 и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @Асхаттт Что есть "трабла"? У Вас полный путь к файлу где-нибудь хранится?

Comment: Что делает моя прога: 1. Сканирует по выбору директорию на имя, путь, размер, формат и т.д.

Comment: 2. Отправляет все это в бд мускул. 3. Далее нажимаем заполнить данные бд, выгружаются в наш dbgrid, сортируем как хотим. 4. Открываем любой файл из dbgrid, вот тут и встал

Comment: Помог Ваш код, спасибо, но для упрощения задачи привязал форм2 и там реализовал редакторы